# More than 5 touch points on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

When I put a sixth finger down in my iPhone app, all 5 existing touch points are cancelled. (This doesn't happen on iPad which supports 10 (or was it 11?) fingers)

It's probably impossible without jailbreaking, but I was wondering if this behavior is documented anywhere.

Comment: Why would you need the 6th finger, just curious?

Comment: There's no way to conceivably use >5 fingers on a usual iphone, but it is slightly more practical (still not very, admittedly) on an iPhone 6+. I have no legit use for it. I am just probing to see where the limits are. I already switched my code to make do with 5 max touches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the number of touch points is a hardware limitation. If you're writing an app to find the six-fingered man who killed your father, you'd best hope he has an iPad.